# C# implement Iterator Pattern and early return empty enumerable if one iterator is not valid

Tags: c#, iterator, ienumerable, yield, enumerable

I want to extract two foreach´s which iterate over mostly the same list but one has an early exit if one element is not valid and the other will only be executed if the other collected the data correctly. Therefor I want to use the iterator-pattern.

Thats a scheme of the use case:

```
foreach (var material in matrix.Materials)
        {
            var validationResult = materialValidator.Validate(material);
            if (validationResult.IsValid == false)
            {
                return;
            }

            validMaterials.Add(
                new Tuple<IMaterial, string>(
                    materialValidator.CurrentMaterial,
                    material.TextMask));
        }

        foreach (var tuple in validMaterials)
        {
            var material = tuple.Item1;
            var text = tuple.Item2;

            material.SetSelcted(true);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) == false)
            {
                module.SetTextMask(textMask);
            }
        }
```

But what I want is to iterate the enumerable if there are valid materials e.g:

```
    var enumerable = new MaterialsEnumerable(matrix.Materials)
    foreach (var iterator in enumerable)
    {
        iterator.Material.SetSelcted(true);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(iterator.Text) == false)
        {
            module.SetTextMask(iterator.Text);
        }
    }
```

And the implementation of MaterialsEnumerable so good as follows, with one missing detail: how do I yield return an empty enumerable at one path?

```
public IEnumerator<MaterialIterator> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var material in this.materials)
        {
            var result = this.validator.Validate(material);
            if (result.IsValid == false)
            {
                return Enumerable.Empty<MaterialIterator>(); // <- this doesn´t work
            }

            yield return new MaterialIterator(
                this.validator.CurrentMaterial,
                material.TextMask);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're after. If `result.IsValid == false` do you want to stop yielding items, i.e. exit the `foreach`? If that's the case, then you can just `yield break;`.

Comment: you return Enumerable.Empty when the first result is not valid. I guess you should continue there instead of return

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you don't want any of the calls to `material.SetSelcted(true);` made if any of the materials are not valid.

There is no way to do this without traversing the (or a) list twice.

We can make the code a little cleaner while still having it fail early.

Assuming that `matrix.Materials` is an array, list, or some other `ICollection<Material>` then this is quite efficient.

```
var count =
    matrix
        .Materials
        .TakeWhile(x => materialValidator.Validate(x).IsValid)
        .Count();

if (matrix.Materials.Count() == count)
{
    foreach (var material in matrix.Materials)
    {
        material.SetSelcted(true);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(material.TextMask) == false)
        {
            module.SetTextMask(material.TextMask);
        }
    }
}
```

The `TakeWhile` allows the iteration to stop early. If the counts match then the entire list was checked and we can proceed on the original collection as it's all been validated.

This approach doesn't create any temporary list and is efficient as possible.

Answer (score -1):

My Solution is to yield break if one element is invalid:

```
public IEnumerator<MaterialIterator> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (this.materials.Any(material => this.validator.Validate(material).IsValid == false))
        {
            yield break;
        }

        foreach (var material in this.materials)
        {
            yield return new MaterialIterator(
                this.validator.CurrentMaterial,
                material.TextMask);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The solution to what? The question is unclear, the wrong terms are used, there's no need to reimplement the iterator pattern already implemented by `foreach` and IEnumerable. I suspect what you really needed was `materials.Where(m=>validator.Validate(m).IsValid).Select(m=>new Whatever(m.TextMask));`. Or `materials.Select(m=>new {Material=m,IsValid=validator.Validate(m).IsValid})`.

Comment: As simple as reduce complexity

Comment: You have made this considerably more complicated and introduced possible bugs further down the track if ever you wish to enumerate through the list normally.

Answer (score -1):

Ok first, your 'solution' above is overly complex and **will** cause bugs down the road. Your original attempt also has extra memory in use and cpu cycles (although C# .Net 7 will reduce this issue, it's bad practice) as you are doing 2 loops in place of 1.

First you need to simplify your code, pull that validation function out of your data object (make it a static extension of the object maybe).

```
public static bool IsValid(this Material material)
{
    //The checking code to check the material is valid
}
```

So if you JUST want to process only lists with only valid samples in them (as described in the OP) then you refactor your loop and code something like:

```
if(matrix.Materials.Any(x=> !x.IsValid())
{
    throw new Exception("Maybe log the thrown issues, or you could do something else with it");
}

foreach(var item in matrix.Materials) 
{
    //Do the stuff you want to do to each element in lists that only contain valid materials
}
```

If you wanted all the **valid** materials from the list (skipping any invalid materials) it would be more like the following without the first if statement.

```
foreach(var item in matrix.Materials.Where(x => x.IsValid())
{
    //do stuff for each valid material
}
```

Always make sure to put you loop conditions in the loop statement, break is ok in some rare circumstances, but you should never use continue as it means you are allocating memory when you do not need to be in any foreach loop and you are breaking the loop control pattern.

Also when you come back after 6 months to edit this, it will be much easier to see what the loop is doing especially if your continue/break is not the first element in the loop.

Answer (score -2):

You can combine the two loops when you continue if the material is not valid.

```
 foreach (var material in matrix.Materials)
        {
            var validationResult = materialValidator.Validate(material);
            if (!validationResult.IsValid)
            {
                continue;
            }
    
            material.SetSelected(true);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(material.TextMask))
            {
                module.SetTextMask(material.TextMask);
            }
    
            yield return material;
        }
```

Comment: That is unlikly wrong, because if one element is invalid, the second iteration will not take place. If I use continue valid-instance would be SetSelected aso but that is unwanted.

Comment: Well i think i misunderstood what you are after. Anyway im glad you have found an answer.

Comment: Do not use continues inside a loop (Unless you are using C or a lower level language), you break the loop control pattern and there is no need for it in higher-level languages particularly C#.